# Python Nested Loop Comprehension

Tags: python

I am trying to set a "word_count" variable by looping through sentences in a file. The file looks like:

> I am Sam
>   I am Alex
>   Alex likes Sam

I can do:

```
word_count = 0
for line in file:
    word_count += enumerate(line.split())
```

How do I make this one line?

Comment: Shoudn't it be `len` instead of `enumerate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to do this

```
word_count = sum(len(line.split()) for line in file)
```

Comment: Thanks for jogging my memory. You need to do `word_count = sum(len(line.split()) for line in file)`

Comment: @Adam_G So sorry, missed that len, Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum` along with the `len` function to achieve this in one line

```
word_count = sum(len(line.split()) for line in file)
```